# Plasma field particle accelerators

Tags: particle-physics, particle-accelerators

I was discussing about particle accelerators with my friends and it came to my mind whether it is anyway possible to make a table-top accelerator(accelerator that can fit on a table). I asked this to my professor and he mentioned something about plasma field accelerator.He said that charged particle passing through a plasma created by laser pulse can get acclerated. How can plasma accelerate charged particles? What will be the maximum energy we can achieve using such accelerator?What is the progress towards the development of such science? Will it be really a table-top accelerator?

Comment: A conventional CRT tube is a tabletop accelerator. It even creates an easily measurable amount of x-rays (which is unknown to the general public or there would probably have been massive panic about the government secretly irradiating the population :-)). So how much time did you spend on google to research the topic? Voting to close for insufficient effort and because this is essentially an engineering question.

Comment: @curiousone I was talking about accelerators with significant amount of energy to do experiment with

Comment: @physics101 There was recently a report of a tabletop accelerator a while back. It will probably come out with a google search.

Comment: You can do plenty of interesting physics experiments with 15keV electron energy. :-)

Comment: @curiousone I want energy in the range of few GeV's.

Comment: Then your best bet is to go to a facility with a working accelerator that can produce a couple of GeVs. What kind of research are you going to do with a couple of GeVs? Just curious.

Comment: @curiousone I am not going to do any kind of research but I am just CURIOUS if this amount of energy can be achieved on a compact scale.

Comment: Are you curious enough to google "plasma field accelerator"? Did you? If you did, which result page left you wanting for a detailed answer?

Comment: I googled it then I was just curious if any curious one can answer it better.

Comment: About this tabletop at the moment: http://www.ioq.uni-jena.de/en/Laser+systems/POLARIS.html "The POLARIS system is built in a laboratory with an area of 250 m².". The problem is, that you need a pretty large laser. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_acceleration) says the energy record is in the low GeV regime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your professor was probably talking about [plasma acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_acceleration).

To explain the details of what plasma acceleration is and how it works seems inappropriate here given the wide availablity of articles on the Internet, so let's concentrate on the question of scale.

With a linear accelerator one of the key parameters is how much energy can be transferred to the accelerating particle per unit distance. As far as I know the current most powerful linear accelerator is the [SLAC accelerator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLAC_National_Accelerator_Laboratory) and it takes 3km to accelerate electrons to 50GeV. While plasma acceleration is still at the proof of principle stage it has been proven possible to accelerate particles by about a Gev per cm. This means that the 3km SLAC accelerator could be shrunk down to a size of 50cm, which would indeed fit on the top of my table.

But there are two points that need to be made:

1. A full scale plasma accelerator is a long way off yet. To take the proof of principle trials to a production accelerator remains a massive undertaking.
2. While the beam line of a plasma accelerator may be relatively short, it will require a massive supporting infrastructure. Your table would be surrounded by several aircraft hangers worth of other hardware.