# About Direct Laser Acceleration

Tags: laser, accelerator-physics

How does this Lawson–Woodward theorem work. I read on the wiki that the particles cannot be accelerated by lasers. But I do see acceleration of electrons with free space. I wonder how this is done.

https://rdcu.be/c0fRw

http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevAccelBeams.19.021303

In addition, I have seen some designs that utilize the center-focusing force in the ion channel to realize the design of short-Periodic undulators, and combine them with plasma accelerators to realize compact free-electron lasers. Can it be achieved in direct laser acceleration, generating a center-pointing focused field as a short-wavelength undulator.

Comment: relevant https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/206470/plasma-field-particle-accelerators

Comment: *"I read on the wiki that the particles cannot be accelerated by lasers."* Where? Wikipedia's [current stub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawson%E2%80%93Woodward_theorem) for the theorem is very careful to say that laser-based accelerators have to break on of the hypothesis of the theorem, not that lasers can't in principle accelerate particles.